# hlexists() for hilight group name or syntax groupname, or both?

Tags: vimscript

My understanding of how `hlexists()` work is that it checks for groupname.

I am assuming that there are two kinds of groupnames:

- highlight
- syntax

Does it work not only on groupname provided by the `hi link` command, but also on detecting `syntax` groupname as well?

If not, what is the correct function that can tell me if such a syntax groupname got created or not?

Comment: (I admit I havent looked at the help for this function) is there a part of the documentation that’s unclear? Or do you have a specific problem to solve (your last sentence hints at one)?

Comment: yeah, does it work for syntax-provided groupname or highlight groupname, if I assumed correctly that they are a separate thing?  Updated question for clarity

Comment: See `:h hlexists()`. The answer is "definitely, yes".

Comment: @Matt, so... both  syntax-provided groupname and highlight groupname, that `hlexists()` works for?  Then I have a bug.

Comment: @Matt, you can post an answer so I can accept (for a quick boost of your rank).